# calling images from xml to html

Tags: html, xml, image, call

I write this code in XML and I want to call these images "Luffy" and "Zoro" to HTML 
please can someone help me ??

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<Pictures>
    <One_Piece>
        <Luffy><img src="images/Luffy1.png"></img></Luffy>
        <Zoro><img src="images/Zoro1.png></Zoro>
    </One_Piece>
</Pictures>
```

what shall I write in js?